Как передать цвет в CSS через переменную?

Пытаюсь при построении html-формы передать цвет из БД.
css код для обоих изображений одинаковый
.cur_color {
     background-color: currentColor;
           }

Это html код первого изображения. Код работает и если указать цвет в HEX формате, и если указать просто название цвета.
<td>
   <select class="cur_color" style='background: #e83e8c'>
            <option th:text="${stat.colorStatus.name}"></option>
            <option
                   th:each="color: ${allColors}"
                   th:if="${stat.colorStatus.name}!=${color.name}"
                   th:value="${color.id}"
                   th:text="${color.name}">
            </option>
    </select>
</td>

Но если задать цвет через переменную, то все строки окрашиваются в черый цвет (изображение 2).
<td>
   <select class="cur_color" style='background: "${stat.colorStatus.codHtml}"'>
            <option th:text="${stat.colorStatus.name}"></option>
            <option
                   th:each="color: ${allColors}"
                   th:if="${stat.colorStatus.name}!=${color.name}"
                   th:value="${color.id}"
                   th:text="${color.name}">
            </option>
    </select>
</td>

Может кто-нибудь сказать как передать цвет через переменную?

Потому что откуда там взялись кавычки? Передавать надо вот так, если в значении переменной уже есть решётка: style='background: ${stat.colorStatus.codHtml}' или вот так, если решетки нет: style='background: #${stat.colorStatus.codHtml}'

По-моему, знак доллара не прокатывает вне th:-атрибутов. Попробуйте заменить style на th:style.
